# Data show on form but wont saved into db

Tags: php

I got stack i tried to custom code but the script did not saved the echo value into the DB.

here what I am doing so far:

```
function give_basic_fees_js() {
    ?>
    <script>
        <?php //Generate

$digits_needed=3;

global $random_number;

$random_number =''; // set up a blank string

$count=0;

while ( $count < $digits_needed ) {
    $random_digit = mt_rand(0, 9);

    $random_number .= $random_digit;
    $count++;
}?>
        var give_global_vars;
        //JS for Basic Fee calculation on the fly.
        jQuery(function ($) {
            /**
             * Event Triggers
             */
            //When document runs.
            $(document).ready(give_basic_update_percentage());
            //If donation amount update is triggered.
            $(document).on('give_donation_value_updated', function () {
                give_basic_update_percentage();
            });
            //If the donation.
            $(document).on('blur', '.give-donation-amount .give-text-input', function (e) {
                give_basic_update_percentage();
            });
            /**
             * JS update logic - Basic update percentage JS.
             */
            function give_basic_update_percentage() {
                //Set vars
                var percentage = <?php echo $random_number; ?>;
                var current_total = $('input[name="give-amount"]').val();
                //Unformat current total so fee calculation is correct for larger donations.
                current_total = Math.abs(parseFloat(accounting.unformat(current_total, give_global_vars.decimal_separator)));
                var fee = percentage;
                var new_total = current_total + fee;
                //Set the custom amount input value format properly
                var format_args = {
                    symbol: give_global_vars.currency_sign,
                    decimal: give_global_vars.decimal_separator,
                    thousand: give_global_vars.thousands_separator,
                    precision: give_global_vars.number_decimals
                };
                fee = accounting.formatMoney(fee, format_args);
                new_total = accounting.formatMoney(new_total, format_args);
                //Update fee information text.
                $('span.give-basic-fee-amount').text(fee);
                //Update final total text.
                $('.give-final-total-amount').text(new_total);
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'give_basic_fees_js' );
/**
 * Adds the fee to the DB upon submit.
 *
 * @param $sanitized_amount
 *
 * @return string
 */
function give_basic_fees_add_fee( $sanitized_amount ) {
    //$fee_percentage = (int) give_get_option( 399 );
    $fee            = $sanitized_amount;
    $new_total      = $fee + percentage;
    return $new_total;
}
add_filter( 'give_donation_total', 'give_basic_fees_add_fee', 1, 1 );
```

So I want to record into DB the $new_total value with formula fee + random_number of percentage

Thanks

Comment: I can't spot any db interaction in your code.

Comment: This is actually my custom function for WordPress CMS

Comment: ok, we can see that. But where's the database code that you're stuck with? If your problem is with writing to the database, you need to show us how you're doing that. If you haven't written it yet, you need to make a start and then ask a specific question if you run into difficulties.

Comment: Maybe I got wrong to write the question. What I want is to get the same random number value generated at the up line (appeared) at form before submit. Right now, the random number is different. For example before press the submit button the random number showed as: xxx.789 but when I pressed submit button the value record on db is: xxx.456. I mean the script generate the new one when button pressed :(

Comment: what do you mean by the "up line"??? Anyway, if you want to persist the number between page refreshes (i.e. between when the page first loads and when it posts back (the form submit)) then you need to either put it in a hidden field on the form, and then read that field at postback, or store it in the PHP session and read it from there. And also set an if condition to control whether a new random number is generated or not when the script executes at the postback.